# Twig - variable set in template will not render will called later

Tags: twig

I am setting a variable in a twig template:

```
{% set precentage = item.getPercentComplete(requested, fulfilled) %}
```

If I print the variable using

```
{{ precentage }}
```

It works fine. However, if I print it inside of an attribute - like this:

```
      <div class="success progress" role="progressbar" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="{{ percentage }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <div class="progress-meter" style="width: {{ percentage }}%">
          <p class="progress-meter-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It returns nothing. I cannot figure out why it prints in the first case, but returns nothing in the second.

Comment: You set p**re**centage and you use p**er**centage, typo error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a typo: use `percentage` instead of `precentage`

So try:

```
{% set percentage = item.getPercentComplete(requested, fulfilled) %}
```

instead of:

```
{% set precentage = item.getPercentComplete(requested, fulfilled) %}
```

Check [this](https://twigfiddle.com/cyl5i4) example

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that.